# Not able to upload .ear to Jboss 6.4 on unix through console

Tags: unix, jboss

Recently I have installed Jboss 6.4 on linux. Its starting correctly but while uploading ear to it through console I am stuck with message "Your request is being processed ...". Please help.

Comment: two things to check 1. don't you have a F/S full? 2. what's in the `server.log`?

Comment: @J.Chomel i have checked F/S its not full, and i don't see any error in 'server.log'